# Как обновить содержимое кастомного Drawable?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

Как обновить уже созданный Drawable имея Bitmap без создания нового Drawable?
Т.е., примерно случай примерно такой:

```
// сначала создается и используется Drawable
Drawable drawable = new MyDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
// Затем прилетает новый Bitmap, который необходимо загрузить в Drawable
makeSomeAsyncOperation((newBitmap) -> drawable.setBitmap(newBitmap));
```

MyDrawable выглядит примерно так:

```
class MyDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    public void setBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Немного специфичная реализация, но другой путь тут не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Класс `BitmapDrawable` имеет скрытый метод `setBitmap`. Можете попробовать вызвать его, используя рефлексию:

```
public class MyDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    public void updateBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) throws NoSuchMethodException,
            InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Class c = getClass().getSuperclass();
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("setBitmap", Bitmap.class);
        if (!m.isAccessible()) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
        }
        m.invoke(this, bitmap);
    }
}
```

Так как данный метод скрытый, значит разработчики SDK не хотели бы чтобы его кто-то использовал. Так что данный код может перестать работать в любой следующей версии. Я **не рекомендую** использовать данный способ, просто описал, что такое возможно.